# PhotoSwipe 5 UI-Elements, retrieve the datasource url of the current image

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

In PhotoSwipe 5 UI-Elements, I want to create a function that needs to access to the current image data source.
I don't know how to retrieve the datasource url of the current image.
Does anyone have a code example?
Best regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe try another alternative, for example, for Fancybox5 it would be as simple as `Fancybox.getInstance().getSlide().src`